# Carousel stopped displaying images on blogger

Tags: jquery, image, carousel, blogger

I am very new to coding and i have used a template and then made edits where needed. Everything worked fine on my blog and then i was accepted for google adsense (no idea if this caused it or was a coincidence) the images stopped displaying.

The carousel which pulls in my previous posts has stopped displaying images, in the code it has a url for 'image not found'. I am not sure why or how i fix this, please help me.

This is the part of the code used for the carousel:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <div class='featured-area'>
        <div id='carousel'>
            <script>
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts1\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</b:if>
```

Comment: `url for 'image not found'` Means what it means. Your src attributes for these images have wrong path